# Why this function variable only works if it's static?

Tags: c++, static, stdvector

I'm trying to put a bunch of sounds in a `std::vector` because it's very convenient.

I'm using an auxiliary variable called `laser`, load the sound into it and, if it's everything ok, `push_back` into the vector.
When I try to play any the sound, nothing happens, not even error messages which should be printed if anything goes wrong.

Just for curiosity I made `laser` `static` and *voilá*, it works flawlessly (or it seems to).

I'd like to know why.

Header file:

```
// audio_system.h
#ifndef KUGE_HEADERS_AUDIO_SYSTEM_H_
#define KUGE_HEADERS_AUDIO_SYSTEM_H_

#include "event.h"
#include "system.h"
#include "../sdl2_wrappers/sdl2_wrappers.h"
#include "../include/resources_path.h"
#include <vector>

namespace kuge {

class AudioSystem : virtual public System {
 public:
  AudioSystem(EventBus& bus): System(bus) {}
  void handleEvent(const Event& event);
  static bool loadResources();

 private:
  static void generateRandomSequence();
  
  static std::vector<ktp::SDL2_Sound> lasers_;
};

} // end namespace kuge

#endif // KUGE_HEADERS_AUDIO_SYSTEM_H_
```

cpp file:

```
#include "event_bus.h"
#include "audio_system.h"

std::vector<ktp::SDL2_Sound> kuge::AudioSystem::lasers_{};

void kuge::AudioSystem::generateRandomSequence() {}

void kuge::AudioSystem::handleEvent(const Event& event) {
  switch (event.getType()) {
    case EventTypes::LaserFired:
      if (lasers_[0].play() == -1) {
        ktp::logSDLError("laser_.play");
      }
      break;
    
    default:
      break;
  }
}

bool kuge::AudioSystem::loadResources() {
  static ktp::SDL2_Sound laser{};            // here! If I don't make this static, nothing happens
  if (!laser.loadSound(ktp::getResourcesPath() + "sounds/laser2.wav")) {
    return false;
  } else {
    lasers_.push_back(laser);
  }
  ktp::logMessage("AudioSystem: resources loaded.");
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Does `ktp::SDL2_Sound` respect rule of 3/5/0 ?

Comment: `ktp::SDL2_Sound` has no operator overrides, no constructor and a destructor which frees the raw pointer passed by `Mix_LoadWAV`. So I think the answer to your question it's: no.                                                                                                                                      I'm going to try this with smart pointers and follow the rule of 0 to see what happens!

Comment: @AlexCB just be wary of something. If you have a pointer to a C object, you may need to call the library's destructor function. You can do that by writing a custom deleter for `std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so following the advices from the comments, I've made the following changes to make `ktp::SDL2_Sound` class follow the rule of 0 and now it works without the need to set the `laser` variable to `static`. This solves the problem, but **I'm still not sure why it worked being `static`.**

```
class SDL2_Sound {
 public:
  //~SDL2_Sound() { free(); }       // now I don't need any destructor
  
  bool loadSound(const std::string& path);
  int play(int loops = 0);

 private:
  void free();
  // Mix_Chunk* sound_ = nullptr;   // old raw pointer
  std::shared_ptr<Mix_Chunk> sound_{};
};


/* void ktp::SDL2_Sound::free() {   
  if (sound_ != nullptr) {
    Mix_FreeChunk(sound_);
    sound_ = nullptr;
  }
} */

bool ktp::SDL2_Sound::loadSound(const std::string& path) {
  //free();
  sound_.reset(Mix_LoadWAV(path.c_str()), &Mix_FreeChunk);
  //sound_ = Mix_LoadWAV(path.c_str());
  if (sound_ == nullptr) {
    ktp::logSDLError("Mix_LoadWAV", path);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: `static` hides some issues, as destructor is no longer called (might be when `std::vector` resize its internal buffer).